# Getting incorrect output in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am getting surprised below error in PL/SQL

```
FCBD(i)='DEUT TRA USD RM TRAD UK, GB02DEUT40508124381319 (USD)',

dbms_output.put_line(INSTR(FCBD(i),' ',INSTR(FCBD(i),',',1,1),2));  output //48
dbms_output.put_line(INSTR(FCBD(i),',',1,1)+2);  output //26
```

Now I am trying to subtract second from first so output should be 48-26=22 but it is 26. it is giving extra 4 for every string,

```
dbms_output.put_line(INSTR(FCBD(i),' ',INSTR(FCBD(i),',',1,1),2)-INSTR(FCBD(i),',',1,1)+2);
```

output coming 26

what logical issue is in above statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help if you showed all you did, because - it works for me.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> declare
  2    fcbd varchar2(100) := 'DEUT TRA USD RM TRAD UK, GB02DEUT40508124381319 (USD)';
  3    a varchar2(10);
  4    b varchar2(10);
  5    c number;
  6  begin
  7    a := INSTR(FCBD,' ',INSTR(FCBD,',',1,1),2);
  8    b := INSTR(FCBD,',',1,1)+2;
  9
 10    c := to_number(a) - to_number(b);
 11
 12    dbms_output.put_line('a = ' || a ||', b = ' || b);
 13    dbms_output.put_line('c = a - b = ' || c);
 14
 15    dbms_output.put_line(to_number(INSTR(FCBD,' ',INSTR(FCBD,',',1,1),2))-
 16                         to_number(INSTR(FCBD,',',1,1)+2));
 17  end;
 18  /
a = 48, b = 26
c = a - b = 22
22

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

It is `TO_NUMBER` you're missing, I'd say. Don't subtract *strings*, subtract *numbers*. See lines #15 and 16.

Also, when putting a minus sign in front of a bracketed expression, all signs within it are **changed** so your `+2` becomes `-2`.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to change `+` to `-` here.

Just fix '+2' here
`dbms_output.put_line(INSTR(FCBD(i),' ',INSTR(FCBD(i),',',1,1),2)-INSTR(FCBD(i),',',1,1)+2);` 
to `dbms_output.put_line(INSTR(FCBD(i),' ',INSTR(FCBD(i),',',1,1),2)-INSTR(FCBD(i),',',1,1)-2);`

Last one should be -2.

`a - (b+c)` should be `a - b - c`, not `a - b +c`